# SSRS development with Azure Analysis Services data source and Azure AAD with MFA / Okta

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, azure-analysis-services

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to connect to an Azure Analysis Services using Azure AAD account with MFA.

I've installed the SSAS [latest drivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/client-libraries?view=asallproducts-allversions#windows-installer).

- I have Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services (AdomdClient) as the data source type and I'm able to test the connection (it prompts for Okta MFA)

[image]

- I'm able to create a dataset and use the query designer.

When previewing the report in VS, it returns this error:

```
The server did not provide a meaningful reply. This might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.
```

If I change the data source to prompt for credentials, I receive this error:

```
Authentication failed: User ID and password are required when user interface is not available
```

[image]

[image]

Visual Studio 2019 16.10. Latest version of SSRS extension (2.6.11). Including power bi tag since it might be relevant too.

Answer (score 0):

We faced a similar issue.

Ensure the user whose credentials you insert within the datasource are excluded from MFA within Azure AD policy.

Comment: Thanks, but we've had it work before with MFA enabled for the credentials. To be clear, I'm referring to previewing the report in Visual Studio (not when it's deployed in production).